# Erro 'x' deve ser numérico

Tags: r

Estou aprendendo a trabalhar com o R ainda. Estou tentando construir um dendrograma a partir de testes de correlação, entre dados isotópicos e meteorológicos. Fiz o seguinte:

```
RC <- read.csv("RCmatrix.csv")
head(RC)
dim(RC)
summary (RC)
cormat <- round(cor(RC),2)
Quando chego aqui aparece: Error in cor(RC) : 'x' deve ser numérico

head(cormat)
dim(cormat)

library(heatmaply)
heatmaply(cor(RC), margins = c(40,130),
          k_col = 2, k_row = 2, colors = Spectral, seriate = "OLO",
          limits = c(-1,1))
```

Minha matriz de dados tem 288 linhas e 18 colunas.

Comment: Olha, com um pedaço do código fica mais fácil de ajudar, você pode usar `dput(head(RC))`. Recomendo tentar no console `class(RC)` ou `typeof(RC)` pra ver se ela tá em formato numérico.

Comment: O `summary` deve dar uma pista. Que tipo de dados são, todos numéricos? Tente também `str(RC)` e corra o `cor` só para as colunas numéricas, de classe `"numeric"` ou `"integer"`.

Comment: `i_col <- sapply(RC, class) %in% c("integer", "numeric");cor(RC[which(i_col)])`